# Annotating constructor parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, annotations

Annotating constructor parameters seems to do nothing when compiled to bytecode. I get no compiler warnings either.

The following works. `getAnnotations` for the `name` field returns `javax.annotation.Nullable`.

```
class Person {
    @Nullable var name: String = _;
}
```

The following doesn't, neither with `val` or `var`.

```
class Person(@Nullable var name: String)
```

This is probably not intentional, so is there something I am missing or should I go file a bug report?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to specify what should get annotated when you specify annotations on constructor parameters.

To do that annotate your annotation with one ore more annotations from `scala.annotation.target`, e.g. `getter`, `setter` or as in your case `field`:

```
import annotation.target.field

class Person(@(Nullable @field) var name: String)
```

You can also use type aliases for that:

```
type NullableField = Nullable @field

class Person(@NullableField var name: String)
```

### Update Scala 2.12

Now  this specific annotation and others are in the package **scala.annotation.meta** rather than scala.annotation.target

```
import scala.annotation.meta.{field, param}
```

Comment: More information can be found here: http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3421 and http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/3596

Comment: The corresponding documentation is now at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.annotation.meta.package

Comment: That documentation link didn't work for me, but this does: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/annotation/meta/index.html